# VB6 Crashing with Run-Time Error 5 with only msgbox

Tags: vb6

I'm not really sure why VB6 is crashing. I have a form with a checkbox and if it's checked, then I `msgbox` a value. The only thing I have in that Subroutine is the msgbox.

I'm running this on Windows 10. I've already set the compatibility mode to Windows XP but that doesn't change the behavior that's happening.

How do I fix this? I'm not even sure what the issue is.

```
Private Sub ChkNonSerialize_Click()
  MsgBox "Test"
End Sub
```

Comment: Any other code in the app?  How about third-party controls?  If you start a new application with only the checkbox and that code, does it still crash?

Comment: There is other code in the app but debug mode shows VB hitting only the routine where its crashing. This only happens on Windows 10 so it's making me wonder if this is a 10 thing? The problem does not appear when creating a new app

Comment: I've not experienced any Win10 specific issues, and I develop and run a huge app every day on Win10.

Comment: "The problem does not appear when creating a new app"  So it is specific to that app in question.  It has something loaded that triggers when the MsgBox appears.  You probably need some kind of update (third-party or MS patch) to fix the issue.  I don't think anyone is going to be able to help you with this issue without more details.

Comment: @BrianMStafford, I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. I believe there is an issue somewhere but where is the issue. If I comment out everything in that routine, then I don't get the error. So, basically, if the routine is empty, it works. If I do anything inside of it, I will get runtime error 5 **sometimes**. It's the intermittency that is making this difficult for me

Comment: @Idle_Mind, thanks. I'm really not sure how to even go about troubleshooting this. What makes it more difficult is that it's intermittent. I've never seen the app crash under Windows 7 or XP, which is making me think that the problem is with Windows 10. But, Brian Stafford says he's running a large program on 10 with no issues, so I'm not sure what to think.

Comment: Exactly...so it should work under Windows 10 but doesn't.  Which supports my assertion that you need some kind of update.  It is also possible that some other update on your system "broke" a component/subsystem that VB6 relied upon.  In that case you'd have to re-install VB6 to fix the issue.  I feel for you...you've got so little to go upon.  =/

Comment: @Idle_Mind, I'm not real VB savvy, so I'm kind of lost on how to even approach this issue. I know my machine is missing updates and I can certainly do that much, but I'm not too hopeful. Maybe reinstalling VB6 will help. At any rate, I can do that and report back here with my findings. I appreciate the help, guys.

Comment: Wait... This might be something to consider.. I have VB6, 2008, 2010 and 2019 on this same machine where my code is dying. Could all these different versions be the reason?

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue.  They all can co-exist and run side-by-side with each other.  I have tons of versions of Visual Studio on my machine right now (and did have VB6 on my system long ago as well).

Comment: @Idle_Mind, weird. I'm certain that it's probably something I'm doing. The code looks clean so I'm not really sure. I am in the process of reinstalling VB6 but just noticed that it's not even in my programs list, so I can't even do an uninstall

Comment: What is the exact line that is failing with the error? If you set it to break on all errors, that should show you.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs, Is that a setting or are you referring to `On Error Goto`?

Comment: Its a setting - you should right click in the code window, then select the Toggle menu, and then break on all errors

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs, I am breaking on all errors and I am now able to see what is causing it. Thank you!! Basically, we have an ActiveX timer library that was originally developed on Windows 2000, so I am going to make the assumption that there may be some sort of a conflict going on because it's now running on Windows 10. Would you agree?

Comment: Glad that was helpful. Maybe you should update your question with the new information... but in general I've found that very old VB6 code still continues to work today. The "devil is in the details" of course :)

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs, thanks, and I agree, it's all in the details. There is basically a license key violation that looks like that particular library is throwing. The company that developed this timer for them is no longer around unfortunately. Do you still think it's worth it to post a new question?

Comment: It could be worthwhile... someone else out there may have had the same problem, that's pretty common with VB6 actually.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs, okay, thanks. I'll post the new info now. If there is a fix, I'm very open. Thank you again for staying with me on this.