# VB6 MsgBox and Run-Time Error 5 using SetFocus

Tags: vb6

This is a continuation from my original post, here: [VB6 Crashing with Run-Time Error 5 with only msgbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62283655/vb6-crashing-with-run-time-error-5-with-only-msgbox)

I have this bug narrowed down to one routine now, and thought I might have better luck if I posted my findings.

Just to recap: I have multiple validation checks going on within the application. Whenever one of validation methods fails, I use a `MsgBox` to show the user their error. After the error is shown, I get a run-time 5 error.

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
  TxtLoginScan.SetFocus
End Sub
```

If I rem SetFocus, everything works perfectly; the message boxes will show and there is no run-time error. I read somewhere that the `Let` command may be useful here but I'm not sure. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with this `SetFocus` command?

I need to initially set the focus to my TxtLoginScan textbox.

**EDIT**

---

This is the function that my form is pointing to:

```
Public Function Validate() As Boolean
  If frmLogin.TxtLoginEmpId = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please scan your employee badge"
    Validate = False
    Exit Function
  End If
End Function
```

Also, I just noticed that if I run the program within VB6, the run-time error never shows itself. Only after the executable is compiled do I see it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215750/discussion-on-question-by-nan-vb6-msgbox-and-run-time-error-5-using-setfocus).

Comment: Is there some code in either TxtLoginEmpId_GotFocus() or frmLogin_Deactivate() events? As for the crash not happening in the IDE, check what options you have set in Options->General, "Break on error". Also worth a try: compile to P-Code instead of native. Most of the time programs don't benefit from native code compilation, but it can cause "strange errors" _(avoiding the b** word)_.